# Windows 11: How to reinstall Snip & Sketch

Tags: windows, windows-11, snipping, snipping-tool

I did uninstall the old deprecated snipping tool from windows 11. But now I see "snip & sketch" is uninstalled too!

I removed it via right-clicking on the snipping tool in the start and pressing "uninstall".

I don't know how can I reinstall it! I searched in the Microsoft store but I didn't find it. When I search "Snip & Sketch" or "Snip and Sketch" it won't show up.

Comment: Why did you uninstall the Snip and Sketch to begin with?

Comment: @music2myear I wrote that I wanted to uninstall the deprecated app snipping tool. But it uninstalled both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know how can I reinstall it! I searched in the Microsoft store
> but I didn't find it.

**(A) Using the Store:**  Go to the Microsoft Store and type:

Snip and Sketch

Snip 'n Sketch comes up and you can install it.

Should work just fine

**(B) Power Shell:**  You can also try Powershell

[Installl Snipping tool with Powwshell](https://https:/https://www.windowsdigitals.com/install-uninstall-windows-11-snipping-tool-powershell/)

> You could use the following command to reinstall using PowerShell, if
> you know package name:
>
> If for some reason the Snipping Tool isn’t already available on your
> Windows 11 device, you can easily install it using PowerShell with
> just one line command. Follow the steps outlined below:
>
> Ensure that your PowerShell window, which you opened in administrator
> mode, is active. To install the Snipping Tool, type in the following
> command
>
> Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *Microsoft.ScreenSketch* | Foreach
> {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register
> "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
>
> This command checks for the Snipping Tool package (known as
> Microsoft.ScreenSketch in Windows 11) across all user accounts and
> registers it if not already done.
>
> Wait for the command to execute completely. Depending on your system’s
> speed and current workload, it might take a few moments. Once
> completed, verify the installation. You can do this by navigating to
> the Start Menu and typing “Snipping Tool” or “Screen Sketch”. The app
> should appear in the search results, indicating a successful
> installation and it’s ready for use.

Comment: Your link is dead and your quote critically does not include the actual Package name needed.

Comment: I changed the link to a working link and used the text from the link.   Thank you.